# Unable to verify association in Rails 4 (carrierwave)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was doing some practise work and I stumbled unto a small problem. I'm trying to access images uploaded via the category section. In the CategoryController `show` method I can't seem to access images.

Error:

> ```
> undefined method 'images' for #<Category::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x9350b20>
> ```

Code: Category Controller

```
def show
  @category = Category.find params[:id]
  @categories = Category.all
  @images = @categories.images
end
```

[console log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz9QB.png)

Answer (score 0):

> NoMethodError: Raised when a method is called on a receiver which
>   doesn't have it defined

Category is a class. It doesn't have the images method. I guess instances of Category like `Category.first.images` will have it.

Comment: This returns an array of all the images, however why can't I access it in the CategoryController show method. Am trying to retrieve all the images associated with a particular category. 
Also the images have the category_id when i check the console.

Comment: Then you need  `@category.images`.